# Continuous Integration server for blackberry development? (and certificate signing)

Tags: blackberry, continuous-integration

I overheard another team where I work talking about blackberry development - they are having issues automating builds for blackberry.  In particular there is an issue with certificate signing - they have not been able to figure that out yet - it is a manual step right now.

Granted, they/we are new to handheld development, but any pointers to build server and automating a command line certificate signing would be most welcome.

Specific examples and details are probably needed given the short experience our company has with BB development.

I assume hudson would work fine for this - we just have to figure out a command line for the build and signing.

Answer (score 7):

There are different ant & rapc tools for building BlackBerry project, and me myself prefer [bb ant tools](http://www.slashdev.ca/2007/05/30/blackberry-development-with-ant-eclipse/), but what if you really want to build bb app directly from cmd using only sun java  and rim bb sdk?

[BerryMore - BlackBerry JDE projects Build & Signing automation](http://berrymore.wordpress.com/2008/06/22/blackberry-jde-projects-build-signing-automation/) - custom ant-rapc jar
[Dr.Dobbs BlackBerry Development: Using Apache Ant](http://www.ddj.com/mobile/48800167) - clean ant + wtk

### Build BlackBerry from command line

```
 "{eJDE path}\components\bin\rapc.exe" -quiet import="{eJDE path}\components\lib\net_rim_api.jar" codename={AppName} -midlet {AppName}.rapc [list of resources] [list *.java files]
```

Example:

```
 "c:\Program Files\eclipse_bb\plugins\net.rim.eide.componentpack4.5.0_4.5.0.16\components\bin\rapc.exe" -quiet import="c:\Program Files\eclipse_bb\plugins\net.rim.eide.componentpack4.5.0_4.5.0.16\components\lib\net_rim_api.jar" codename=SO45BgAnim -midlet SO45BgAnim.rapc "src\gifanimation.gif" "src\background.png" "src\SO45BgAnim.java"
```

See also:
[CodeForFun: How to use rapc from RIM… dirty details!](http://codeforfun.wordpress.com/2008/09/09/how-to-use-rapc-from-rim-dirty-details/)

### Sign BlackBerry from command line

```
java -jar "{eJDE path}\components\bin\SignatureTool.jar" -a -c -p {password} {path to *.cod}
```

Example:

```
java -jar "c:\Program Files\eclipse_bb\plugins\net.rim.eide.componentpack4.5.0_4.5.0.16\components\bin\SignatureTool.jar" -a -c -p pwd@123 "D:\Projects\BlackBerry\TestApp\build\TestApp.cod"
```

See also:
[BlackBerry Support Forum - Request Signatures (Sign Your App) From Command Line](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/board/message?message.uid=222214)

Answer (score 2):

We use [BB Ant Tools](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/) and it works great, you can even specify the signing password as an argument so there is no user input required.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is some workaround:

http://blackberry.synclastic.com/blackberry-code-signing-tips/  (not working as 15/05/2012)

and 
http://blog.lightvoid.net/2008/04/28/automated-blackberry-sign-tool-mac-linux-windows/ (points to corporate onidev website as 15/05/2012)

This  one looks even better -

http://www.cive.de/projects/signaturetoolrunner/